# How to calculate the sum of the datatable column in c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, sum, double

hello i am trying to sum up a double column from the database. i have came up with this

```
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   double sum = 0;
   dt = ds.Tables["bug_tasks"];
   foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
   {
       foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
       {
           sum += (double)dr[dc];
       }

   }
   Response.Write(sum);
```

for some odd reason im getting an error with this line

dt = ds.Tables["bug_tasks"];

bug_tasks is the name of the table.

the column i would like to get a total for is called time and its a double

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? We can't help if we don't know the error.

Comment: You are missing some database connection fundamentals. Your sample has no way to know how to reach the database server where the table resides. Take a look at this question as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651853/sql-select-from-database-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

> the column i would like to get a total for is called time and its a double

Then you shouldn't iterate through all columns, only all all rows:

```
double sum = 0;
dt = ds.Tables["bug_tasks"];
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    sum += System.Convert.ToDouble(dr["time"]);
}
Response.Write(sum);
```